# Don't resolve expressions in helm templates when using Intellij Kubernetes plugin

Tags: intellij-idea

Since I installed the Kubernetes plugin in Intellij, expressions like `{{ .Chart.Name }}` get replaced with `user-service` in the UI. Maybe it's being done by a Go Templating plugin. How do I turn this off?

I want to see the actual text which is in the file, not the resolved value.

Comment: What name of your file?

Comment: Seems that feature request covers your case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-236964, doesn't it?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov yes that's it, thanks. So it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that there is an [open feature request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007837900-How-do-you-toggle-template-interpolation-in-Helm-chart-templates-) for this functionality, I assume that it's currently not possible.

In the meantime, I'm going to uninstall the plugin. The value for me is outweighed by the annoyance / confusion of the interpolation feature.